# How to use for loop for listing integer in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I have a state named `rounds` and prop `current_round`. Default value for current_round is 0. What I want to do with these value is that listing buttons with integer. For example, if value of `rounds` is 4, listing buttons of 1, 2, 3 and 4.

```
for (var i =(this.props.order.order.current_round + 1); i<(this.props.order.rounds+1); i++) {

  return (
    <li><button id ={i} class="rounds_btn">{i}</button></li>
    );
  }
```

So to do that, I made for loop like above, but it only shows one button of integer 1..

What is wrong with my code? it doesn't show any errors.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's just return the first value in the render function. you should put the results in a variable and then render this variable.

```
const buttons = [];

for (var i =(this.props.order.order.current_round + 1); i<(this.props.order.rounds+1); i++) {

  buttons.push(
    <li><button id ={i} class="rounds_btn">{i}</button></li>
  );
}

return (<ul> {buttons} </ul>);
```

Answer (score 7):

If you return inside a loop, then the entire function (including the loop) is going to finish executing.

The way to solve this problem is to create an array of *components* then return the entire array after the loop.

```
let { rounds, current_round } = this.props.order;
let list = [];

for (let i = current_round + 1; i < rounds + 1; i++) {
  list.push(
    <li>
      <button id={i} key={i} className="rounds_btn">{i}</button>
    </li>
  );
}

return list;
```

However, the usual way to do this with React is to use the [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
let { order } = this.props;
let nums = range(order.current_round + 1, order.rounds + 1);

return nums.map(i => (
  <li><button key={i} id={i} className='rounds_btn'></button></li>
));

// quick range utility (could use lodash...)
function range(start, end) {
  let nums = [];
  for (let i = start; i < end; i++) nums.push(i);
  return nums;
}
```

In most cases you'll already have your array (list of people, list of items, etc) and all you need to do is map each one to a React component, then return that list.

I've also added a `key` attribute, which React will warn you about, if you forget it for lists of components (helps with reconciling the list if you re-render it in a different order).

Also watch out for using `class` rather than `className`, because `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript, React chooses to use `className` as the JSX prop instead.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be as below in **TS**

```
  const Buttons= (numOfButtons : number) => {
    return (
      <>
        {Array.from(Array(numOfButtons)).map((s, i) => (
         <li><button key={i} id={i} className='rounds_btn'></button></li>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  };
```

Then use the sub-components `<Buttons numOfButtons={3}/>` anywhere you like